# How can I use OR logical operator in U-SQL join?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-lake

```
AND ((Glt.LineNumber == Pct.LineNumber) OR (Glt_1.LineNumber == Pct.UniqueKey_Num));
```

I want to achieve above condition in U-SQL but it's not supported on Azure. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The `OR` SQL syntax is supported in U-SQL (see below simple example).  Are you getting a particular error?

Simple repro:

```
@inputA = 
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        VALUES
            ( (int)1 ), 
            ( (int)2 ),
            ( (int)3 )
     ) AS x ( LineNumber );


@inputB = 
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        VALUES
            ( (int)3, (int)3 ), 
            ( (int)4, (int)4 ),
            ( (int)5, (int)5 )
     ) AS x ( LineNumber, UniqueKey_Num );



@output =
    SELECT Glt. *
    FROM @inputA AS Glt
         INNER JOIN
             @inputA AS Glt_1
         ON Glt.LineNumber == Glt_1.LineNumber
         INNER JOIN
             @inputB AS Pct
         ON Glt.LineNumber == UniqueKey_Num
    WHERE 1 == 1
      AND ((Glt.LineNumber == Pct.LineNumber) OR (Glt_1.LineNumber == Pct.UniqueKey_Num));


OUTPUT @output TO "/output/output.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is about having the OR inside the join condition. That is not supported (only conjunctions are supported). As with any unsupported expression, you could turn it into a CROSS JOIN and move it into the WHERE clause, or leave the part of the condition in the JOIN's ON clause that is supported.

In this case, you could also do one join condition and union (all) it with the second join condition. Depending on the selectivity of the join conditions and availability of statistics, indices etc., this could be faster than a single CROSS JOIN.